# Fixing forced indentation in shell-script-mode for tcsh

Tags: indentation, shell-mode

How do you configure the indentation to work correctly for tcsh shell scripts?

I am unable to make the indentation work correctly when I use the shell-script-mode as it is.

Problem: An indentation of 4 spaces is inserted when I hit enter (when there shouldn't be any indentation!)

How to reproduce this problem?

- Open `\emacs -q&`
- Type `#!/bin/tcsh -f` in an empty buffer and save it as something like `a.csh` so that the `shell-script-mode` is auto-loaded.

When you hit enter at the end of this first and only line, the buffer converts from

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f (no indentation)
```

to

```
    #!/bin/tcsh -f (with indentation)
```

I am on the stable 24.4 version of emacs.

Comment: I can reproduce on 24.3.  Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a fix with a bit of a hack with the help of `edebug-defun`!

The keyword highlighting of shell-script-mode is good. But the problem was that it set the `indent-line-function` to `sh-basic-indent-line` when `sh-shell` was set to `tcsh`. That function caused the extra indentation by 4 spaces.

There is an outdated [`csh-mode.el`](https://github.com/Tux/tcsh/blob/master/csh-mode.el) (last updated in 1999) which does the indentation well but has outdated keyword highlighting info.

So I simply borrowed the useful stuff (`csh-indent-line` and `csh-indent-region` functions) from `csh-mode.el` when I am editing a `.alias` or any file whose extension ends in `*csh`:

```el
(defun my/tcsh-set-indent-functions ()
  (when (or (string-match ".*\\.alias" (buffer-file-name))
            (string-match ".*csh$" (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name))))
    (require 'csh-mode) ; https://github.com/Tux/tcsh/blob/master/csh-mode.el
    (setq-local indent-line-function 'csh-indent-line)
    (setq-local indent-region-function 'csh-indent-region)))
(add-hook 'sh-set-shell-hook #'my/tcsh-set-indent-functions)
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, emacs 24.4 turns on `electric-indent-mode` which makes it indent automatically. Disable it and you won't have that problem anymore:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda() (electric-indent-mode -1)))
```

I set `newline-and-indent` to <kbd>RET</kbd> globally and have no problem:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but the bigger issue is that the indentation is broken for tcsh in `shell-script-mode`. What you suggested will help avoid the issue but as soon as I do `indent-region`, I see the same problem of incorrect indentation.

Comment: Well yes but at least you are able to write `csh` script now, but manually. Probably you should report it to Emacs devs.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the answer by Kaushal Modi this is a more general solution that will use the `csh-indentation` anytime your shell file is set to `tcsh` or `csh`. That way you don't have to enumerate every file that you want this fix to apply to and it won't affect other shell types.

```
(defun my/tcsh-set-indent-functions ()
  (when (string-match ".*csh.*" (symbol-value 'sh-shell-file))
    (require 'csh-mode) ; https://github.com/Tux/tcsh/blob/tux/csh-mode.el
    (setq-local indent-line-function 'csh-indent-line)
    (setq-local indent-region-function 'csh-indent-region)))
(add-hook 'sh-set-shell-hook #'my/tcsh-set-indent-functions)
```

Comment: I have to update my answer, but later I ended up doing something similar. But I still needed to [hack sh-set-shell](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/bc2e0b12393c0933aa19a977d2698fac30a4477d/setup-files/setup-shell.el#L34-L136). The default evaluation of `sh-shell` did not work as I intended.

Comment: @KaushalModi yeah I started to run into some problems as well. But that hack you provided is first rate!